# отправка файла на php curl

Tags: php, curl

помогите с отправкой изображении сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

делаю так:

```
    $imga = '1.jpg'; ///Картинка
    $file = new CURLFile(realpath("$imga")); ///Загружаем картинку
    $ch = curl_init('https://s.taobao.com/image');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('filename' => $file,'name'=>'imgfile',));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($data);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получаю error:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а должен получать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не так.

Comment: Добавьте сообщение об ошибке текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Вообще-то в браузере отправляется дофига заголовков

Comment: Переведите ошибку, может там что полезное.